# External facing customer portal

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

If I have an external-facing portal with say, 80,000 users who need to log in and view their data - would I need to have some sort of custom login system? I mean, they wouldnt have ad accounts so a username and password would need to be created that would be stored somewhere.

What is the practice in this scenario? Is it even feasible?

thx,

KS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Forms Based Authentication with a SQL database providing the account data.  Microsoft has a guide here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317440(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, here is the one for SQL-based providers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg252020(v=office.14).aspx.  The link in the answer is for a custom .NET provider.